# Xlsxwriter: how to disable text wrap in data label?

Tags: xlsxwriter

I'm generating pie charts using XLSX writer, and everything is going perfectly except for one thing: I can't seem to find a way to control the text from wrapping in my data labels (which contain percentage values). Any font size above a 10 causes the '%' symbol to wrap below the digits (you can see this in the image I've attached below). I'm trying to generate many charts, so adjusting them manually could be costly time-wise.

The docs suggest that wrapping can be enabled or disabled from num_format. For cells, this property is set with a 'format' object. However, while data label text has a num_format property, the docs explicitly state that it must be set with a string literal and cannot take a format object. I have no clue how to prevent string wrapping with a string literal format.

Alternatively, I've looked into expanding/reducing the width/height of the data labels. However, this option also seems to be missing from the library.

From what I can tell, none of the other properties seem to suggest a way to avoid wrapping text.

My question is, is there a solution I'm missing? I'll leave some of my output and code below.

Current Code:

```
        chart.add_series({
        'categories' : '={}!B1:C1'.format(product_sheetname),
        'values' : '={}!B2:C2'.format(product_sheetname),
        'data_labels':{
            'percentage':True, 
            'fill': {'color':'#363636'},
            'font': {'name':'Arial (Body)', 'color':'white', 'size':16},
        },
        'points' : [
            {'fill':{'color':'#4471d2'}},
            {'fill':{'color':'#ff871c'}}
        ]        
    })
```

Current Output:

[image]

UPDATE:
A quick fix per the comment below is to scale up the size of the chart in general. While this solves the wrapping issue, it defeats the purpose of using a larger font.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way in XlsxWriter to adjust the size of the data label but Excel should do it automatically to get the best result.

I tried to replicate but didn't see the text wrap that you are getting (even though I tried 3 different versions of Excel):

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart_pie.xlsx')

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write_row('B1', ['Apple', 'Cherry'])
worksheet.write_row('B2', [53, 47])

chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'pie'})

product_sheetname = 'Sheet1'

chart.add_series({
    'categories' : '={}!B1:C1'.format(product_sheetname),
    'values' : '={}!B2:C2'.format(product_sheetname),
    'data_labels':{
        'percentage':True,
        'fill': {'color':'#363636'},
        'font': {'name':'Arial (Body)', 'color':'white', 'size':16},
    },
    'points' : [
        {'fill':{'color':'#4471d2'}},
        {'fill':{'color':'#ff871c'}}
    ]
})

worksheet.insert_chart('B3', chart, {'x_offset': 25, 'y_offset': 10})

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I completely forgot to mention, I've also sized my chart to 2x2 inches (192px x 192px), which, when looking at your results, might be the source of the problem. I will try scaling up and update if that solves the issue

Comment: I don't think scaling should affect the results. I tried various scales and the data label text wasn't wrapped. Are you using Excel to view the results and if so which version?

Comment: At size 16 font, setting the chart size to 2inx2in does cause the text to wrap. Scaling it up either from python or in excel unwraps the text. My xlsxwriter version is 1.3.7, and my excel is version 16.0.11929.20972. That's interesting that the same isn't happening on your end.